# Range-based for loop on a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, foreach, dynamic-arrays

There is a range-based for loop with the syntax:

```
for(auto& i : array)
```

It works with constant arrays but not with pointer based dynamic ones, like

```
int *array = new int[size];
for(auto& i : array)
   cout<< i << endl;
```

It gives errors and warnings about failure of substitution, for instance:

> Error] C:\Users\Siegfred\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled2.cpp:16:16: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)'

How do I use this new syntax with dynamic arrays?

Comment: what does the errors say? At least post **one** error

Comment: it's called range-based for loop and SO and Google have tons of examples

Comment: [Error] C:\Users\Siegfred\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled2.cpp:16:16: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)'

Comment: Second instance is a typo. Should be `for (auto& i: arr)` not `array`.

Comment: Hmm when I read "new C++ for loop on a dynamic array" I thought "what a silly question: it just works!". Then I saw the question and realized "oh, the poster did not mean `vector` when they typed 'dynamic array'..."

Comment: I took the liberty to modify your question a bit. If you feel that it is incorrectly modified there is an edit button under the question in order to fix it (or just write @Default to ping me)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes is there a better definition then "dynamic array" describing what the OP refers to?

Comment: @Default Maybe a *"pointer to a dynamically allocated array"* (a bit cumbersome, but would have made the OP's error of thinking about a pointer as an array more obvious).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To make use of the *range-based for-loop* you have to provide either `begin()` and `end()` member functions or overload the non-member `begin()` and `end()` functions.
In the latter case, you can wrap your range in a `std::pair` and overload `begin()` and `end()` for those:

```
    namespace std {
        template <typename T> T* begin(std::pair<T*, T*> const& p)
        { return p.first; }
        template <typename T> T* end(std::pair<T*, T*> const& p)
        { return p.second; }
    }
```

Now you can use the for-loop like this:

```
    for (auto&& i : std::make_pair(array, array + size))
        cout << i << endl;
```

Note, that the non-member `begin()` and `end()` functions have to be overloaded in the `std` namespace here, because `pair` also resides in namespace `std`. If you don't feel like tampering with the standard namespace, you can simply create your own tiny pair class and overload `begin()` and `end()` in your namespace.

Or, create a thin wrapper around your dynamically allocated array and provide `begin()` and `end()` member functions:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct wrapped_array {
        wrapped_array(T* first, T* last) : begin_ {first}, end_ {last} {}
        wrapped_array(T* first, std::ptrdiff_t size)
            : wrapped_array {first, first + size} {}

        T*  begin() const noexcept { return begin_; }
        T*  end() const noexcept { return end_; }

        T* begin_;
        T* end_;
    };

    template <typename T>
    wrapped_array<T> wrap_array(T* first, std::ptrdiff_t size) noexcept
    { return {first, size}; }
```

And your call site looks like this:

```
    for (auto&& i : wrap_array(array, size))
         std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

[Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3rzx8X$3)

Comment: Is there no built-in construct for this? Anyone who has a dynamic C-style array needs to write their own wrapped_array struct?

Comment: @sffc  Not yet, but there will be in C++20. I present that in my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472203/3002139) below.

Comment: "It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: Gross. . . . . .

Answer (score 19):

You can't use range-for-loop with dynamically allocated arrays, since compiler can't deduce begin and end of this array. You should always use containers instead of it, for example [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
std::vector<int> v(size);
for(const auto& elem: v)
    // do something
```

Comment: well, it worked! i never knew C++ would be this type-safe, i came from C, so a got used to manipulating dynamic and constant arrays in the same way.

Comment: @MauriceRodriguez Well, *C* has this difference between arrays and pointers in exactly the same way. For example `sizeof(array)` returns completely different things in *C*, too, depending on if it's `int *array = malloc(N*sizeof(int));` or `int array[N];`. So it is just because *C* made it easier for you to *incorrectly* ignore this difference, not that this difference wasn't there.

Comment: I disagree that you should *always* use a std::vector over a dynamically allocated array. =) There are cases where it's important to use the dynamic version. Also, since we're using C++11 anyway, std::array is a good idea to consider when you're using a fixed reasonably sized array.

Comment: Could you give me an example, please? Also, `std::array` is good, of course, but you must know it's size at compile time. This may not cover the OP case. As replacement for `std::vector` I can suggest `std::dynarray`(since C++1y) if you don't need to increase size an array's size.

Comment: @soon `dynarray` was voted out of C++14 ("1y") and still only has experimental status at best, so it should probably not be used in production.

Comment: 1. Other answers show how range based loop can be done over dynamically allocated array if its size is known, so "you can't do it" is an overstatement. 2. `std::vector`/`std::array` can't always be used (e.g. imagine having to deal with a legacy interface).

Answer (score 12):

You can't perform a range based loop directly over a dynamically allocated array because all you have is a pointer to the first element. There is no information concerning its size that the compiler can use to perform the loop. The idiomatic C++ solution would be to replace the dynamically allocated array by an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> arr(size);
for(const auto& i : arr)
  std::cout<< i << std::endl;
```

Alternatively, you could use a range type that provides a begin and end iterator based on a pointer and an offset. Have a look at some of the types in the [boost.range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library, or at the [GSL](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md) span proposal (example implementation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), reference for C++20 proposed type [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)).

---

Note that a range based for loop does work for `std::array` objects of fixes size plain arrays:

```
std::array<int,10> arr;
for(const auto& i : arr)
  std::cout<< i << std::endl;

int arr[10] = .... ;
for(const auto& i : arr)
  std::cout<< i << std::endl;
```

but in both cases the size needs to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: You can already range-`for` over a bare automatically allocated array, no need to add the wrapper class just for this. `int a[]{1, 2, 3}; for (auto it: a) std::cout << it << ' ';` Each count of elements creates a distinct type for which `end` can be deduced when compiling the loop.

Comment: 1. Other answers show how range based loop can be done over dynamically allocated array if its size is known, so "you can't do it" is an overstatement. 2. `std::vector`/`std::array` can't always be used (e.g. imagine having to deal with a legacy interface).

Comment: @DevNull Sure, thanks. I edited the answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @DevNull And a section on alternatives when all you have is a pointer and a size.

Answer (score 8):

C++20 adds [`std::span`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), which allows looping like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

int main () {
    auto p = new int[5];
    for (auto &v : std::span(p, 5)) {
        v = 1;
    }
    for (auto v : std::span(p, 5)) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
    delete[] p;
}
```

This is supported by current compilers, e.g. [gcc 10.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) and [clang 7.0.0](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html) and later. ([Live](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html))

Of course, if you have the choice, it is preferable to use `std::vector` over C-style arrays from the get-go.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining `std::begin` and `std::end` for `std::pair` of pointers (defining them in `std::`, by the way, is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)) and rolling out your own wrapper, as [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919834/8414561), you can use `boost::make_iterator_range`:

```
size_t size = 16;
int *dynamic_array = new int[size];
for (const auto& i : boost::make_iterator_range(dynamic_array, dynamic_array + size))
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4203299dec0b222).

Answer (score 1):

From C++20 views, we can use subrange also (`std::ranges::subrange`)

```
auto p = new int[5];

//INPUT DATA TO TEST
int i = 0;
for (auto& v : std::ranges::subrange(p, p + 5)) {
    v = ++i;
}

//USE SUBRANGE
for (auto v : std::ranges::subrange(p, p + 5))
    std::cout << v << '\n';
```