# returning an array address from function in c++ issue

Tags: c++

i'm new to programming , this code gives me syntax error in line => int *result = apply_all(array1,5,array2,3) this is the error: expected primary-expression before '}' token|
i'm trying to write function called apply_all expects 2 arrays of integers and their sizes and dynamically allocates a new array of integers whose size is the product of 2 array sizes.
the function should loop through the 2nd array and multiple each element accross each element of array 1 and store the product in newly created array. the function is returning a pointer of to the newly allocated array.
also i wrote a function which is print to display the 1st & 2nd & newly array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//function prototype
int *apply_all(int *array1 ,int size1,int *array2,int size2);
void print(int *array,int size);



int main()
{
    int array1[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    int array2[] {10,20,30};

    cout << "Array 1:";
    print(array1,5);

    cout << "Array 2:";
    print(array2,3);

    int *result = apply_all(array1,5,array2,3);             
    cout << "Result : ";
    print(result,15);
    delete [] result;
    return 0;
}


int *apply_all(int *array1 ,int size1,int *array2,int size2)
{
        int *result {nullptr};
        result = new int[size1 * size2];   
        for (int i{0};i<size2;i++)          
            for(int j{0};j<size1;j++)          
                  *(result[i*5+j]) = *(array1[i])**(array2[j]);           
        return result;
}


void print(int *array,int size)
{
    for(auto num:array)
        cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: also i was thinking to replace this line *(result[i*5+j]) = *(array1[i])**(array2[j]); to be *(result++)  = *array1[i]**array2[j];   
or create a new variable for ex: k++ in for loop and *(result[k])  = *array1[i]**array2[j];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
*(result[i*5+j]) = *(array1[i])**(array2[j]);
```

since `result[i*5+j]` gives you an `int`, you are trying to dereference an `int`, which is not possible.

You just need to do:

```
result[i*5+j] = array1[i] * array2[j];
```

Also, in `print`, your range-for loop won't work with a pointer. You need to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << array[i] << endl;
```

Also, in `apply_all`, your loop bounds are incorrect. `i` needs to go till `size1`, and `j` needs to go to `size2`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QkiMvs).

Comment: thank you so much but i have 2 questions 
1- *(result[i*5+j]) = *(array1[i])**(array2[j]);  , so this line i've already accessed the array elements because i use array subscript notation [] so i don't need to deference it??  what i understand result now has the address of array in heap. so to access it i can use [] or *
2- why range-for loop won't work with a pointer??
sorry for those beginner questions

Comment: Yes, `[]` and `*` are related like you say. For the second question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904896/range-based-for-loop-on-a-dynamic-array

Comment: thank you :)
i read that in the article you provided You can't use range-for-loop with dynamically allocated arrays, since compiler can't deduce begin and end of this array 
can i use vector with pointer in for range based???
void display (vector<string> *v)
{ for(auto str: *v)
cout << str << endl;}
int main(){
vector<string> str1 ["joe","logan","Jasmine"]
display(&str1);

Comment: You *could*, but just pass in the vector by reference, instead of by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new, a simple work around would be creating an array with buffer space to store your results in and passing the pointer for this into apply_all. You could then write to this array which (being declared in main) should be very easy to access and cause few errors and use a c-string like ending to know when your results are over and to stop printing from the array (c-strings end with a value of 0 so that programs don't read unrelated memory). eg:

```
int buf[99];
apply_all(array_1, size1, array_2, size2, buf, size3);
for (int x = 0; buf[x] != end of buf var; x++;)
{
    print(buf[x])
}
```

and

```
apply_all()
{
    buf[start-end] = whatever you want;
    buf[end + 1] = some variable that won't appear in buffer; //max int size?
}
```